# collection_select and saving a record in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn ruby on rails, writing my own simple app (a to-do list). I now want to add a dropdown menu to select a user to assign the task to.

My schema.rb:

```
create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
t.text     "description"
t.string   "priority"
t.date     "date"
t.time     "time"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.boolean  "done"
t.string   "name"
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Now, in my form I have a field with:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user, User.all, :id, :name ) %>
```

It works as far as displaying my users goes. But, when I try to save, I of course get:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ItemsController#create
```

I already have set up the relationship (users has many task, task has one user). What am I missing? 
Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a 'user_id' column in 'items' table.

```
rails g migration AddUserToItems user_id:integer
rake db:migrate

class Item
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end

class User
  has_many :items
  ...
end

collection_select(:item, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name)
```

Comment: ok let me try that, in the meanwhile i got it working by using the following code:
<%= f.collection_select(:name, User.all, :name, :name ) %>

Comment: try: collection_select(:item, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name).
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= collection_select(:item, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, {:prompt=>true}) %>
                       1.     2.       3.         4.   5.       6.
```

1. The model
2. Where you are storing in the model
3. collect of users
4. what will be saved
5. what is displayed
6. prompt with "please select"

This might help.